# Coldfusion function for fedex shipping calculation

Tags: coldfusion, fedex

How to calculate fedex shipping charges based on weight, for fedex ground or fedex overnight. I need CF functions to do at the time of checkout in an e-commerce site.

Comment: Not to be rude, but you should at least google before posting. The project below came up as the second search result for "ColdFusion fedex".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following component.

[cffedexrates - ColdFusion FedEx Shipping Rates](http://code.google.com/p/cffedexrates/)

> Coldfusion component for calculating shipping rates from FedEx -- simply supply the value, weight and addresses and it returns the type (Overnight Priority, Standard Overnight, 2-day, etc) and it's cost.

**hope this helps**

Comment: this works but does not return all of the rate options.
it only returns FIRST_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_2_DAY, FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER, FEDEX_GROUND

there are many other rates... the most popular being HOMEGROUND DELIVERY

Any ideas how to get ALL the available rates?